# Princomp summary as a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to have the summary of the princomp PCA (has to be princomp) as a dataframe so that I can format the table with kable for a report.

Here is the code I tried to use, it should be clear from this what I want to do;

```
kable( as.data.frame(summary(pca.data)) )
```

I get this error:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(summary(pca.data)) : cannot coerce
>   class ""summary.princomp"" to a data.frame

EDIT: I want the output of sum.data as a dataframe so I can use the kable function to format it.

```
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")

set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
X = sample(1:10), X2 = sample(1:10), X3 = sample(1:10), X4 = sample(1:10), 
X5 = sample(1:10)
)

pca.data <- princomp(data, cor=TRUE)
sum.data <- summary(pca.data)
kable(as.data.frame(sum.data))
```

Comment: I've edited the question with some example code.

Comment: Which part of the output do you want to use for a data frame? Take a look at `names(sum.data)`—the summary is made up of 9 different items

Comment: It was just the printout of the summary when it's run that I wanted, (the variances for each component etc). I have an answer now so it's ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to get the following table

```
Importance of components:
                          Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3     Comp.4     Comp.5
Standard deviation     1.4126051 1.1441266 0.9542661 0.63918520 0.61346533
Proportion of Variance 0.3990906 0.2618052 0.1821247 0.08171154 0.07526794
Cumulative Proportion  0.3990906 0.6608958 0.8430205 0.92473206 1.00000000
```

that's not actually stored anywhere and is only created when you run the `stats:::print.summary.princomp` function. You can extract the part of that function that makes that table. For example

```
pca_importance <- function(x) {
  vars <- x$sdev^2
  vars <- vars/sum(vars)
  rbind(`Standard deviation` = x$sdev, `Proportion of Variance` = vars, 
      `Cumulative Proportion` = cumsum(vars))
}
```

so now you have an object that ktable can use

```
kable( pca_importance(sum.data) )
```